# Request: auto-capitalization of common words

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to have certain words auto-capitalized? People just burp questions and answers with completely ignoring capitals. I find it rather annoying to clean up these, as the asker did not even take a minimal effort to write properly.

Words such as "I", "Canon", "Nikon","AF", different shooting modes. Also first characters of sentences.

Alternatively, we should not accept questions and answers without capitalization. Just scan for those words and refuse to accept the input if those are not corrected.

Comment: I think this is beyond the realm of what StackExchange does. It's really up to the community to moderate and manage content like this. Remember, if you have the reputation, you can always edit any post and correct these kinds of deficiencies.

Comment: Yes, I went up one level to meta.stackexchange.com. It is actually weird that this has been proposed and got highly upvoted and received positive comments, but never got implemented...

Comment: My browser does a lot of that for me these days (drives me nuts sometimes), so that may be a major reason why.

Comment: Those who down-vote: could you please explain why you down-vote? What rule am I against so that you down-vote my question? Rather: give a reasonable answer...

Comment: On Meta, downvoting has a different meaning than on the main site — it can just mean "I disagree with this request". It doesn't mean the downvoter thinks there is a rule violation or even that the question is inherently badly asked. Your reputation isn't affected, and the whole way discussion works on meta is a bit different overall. (I didn't downvote, FWIW; just adding an observation on the convention.)

Answer (score 2):

What about times when someone is talking about the *canon of Depression-era photographs* or using *i* as a lower-case Roman numeral? Also, it's probably not possible to implement this feature completely because the list of proper nouns and other words that should be capitalized is very long and always changing. Furthermore, incorrect capitalization is just one of many errors that we see. There's also poor formatting, capitalization of words that shouldn't be capitalized, spelling errors, poor grammar, generally unclear writing, and so on.

I sympathize with your frustration, but it'd be far more annoying to have SE insist on inappropriate capitalization just because I happen to use a word on some arbitrary list of words for which capitalization is required. Some sort of automatic grammar checker that suggests but doesn't insist upon improvements would be great, and could address more than just the capitalization issue, but that seems like a taller order than the feature you requested.

I'd suggest simply downvoting questions and answers that are sloppy, and perhaps adding a comment to explain the downvote and encourage more attention to detail.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Caleb that it would be hard to implement properly. You *can* downvote for this, but we've actually had new users come in this way and then end up cleaning up their act and becoming valuable community members. (I won't name names.)

Keep in mind also that many posters are not native English speakers and may be coming from a language with different rules for capitalization, punctuation, and grammar.

My approach is:

1. First time someone posts with poor capitalization, just edit, with an edit note explaining that proper capitalization helps the post be viewed in a positive light
2. Second time, same, but with a comment too.
3. Third: comment without editing, possibly downvote.
4. *Still* happening? Downvote liberally, flag as low quality.